# Create new array of dictionary items based on differences

Tags: swift, swift5

I need to compare name and address as a match between two arrays of dictionaries and create a new array of dictionary items as such with updated phone number - persisting the same indexes as array[0], in the newArray[0]

```
array[0] = ["name": "Tom", "address": "123 street", "phone": "000-000-0000"] ["name": "Tim", "address": "321 street", "phone": "001-000-0000"]
["name": "Jo", "address": "123 street", "phone": "002-000-0000"]

array[1] = ["name": "Tom", "address": "555 street", "phone": "100-000-0000"] ["name": "Jon", "address": "12321 street", "phone": "111-111-0000"]
["name": "Tim", "address": "321 street", "phone": "002-000-0000"]
```

RESULTS

```
newArray[0]
["name": "-", "address": "-", "phone": "-"] ["name": "Tim", "address": "321 street", "phone": "111-111-0000"] ["name": "-", "address": "-", "phone": "-"]
```

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us what the issue is with it.

Comment: Why are you not creating an object with that properties and use that instead of dictionaries?